# Running a single test with invoker plugin

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-invoker-plugin

Following is the directory structure for my integration tests

```
 /src/it/first-test  
           -->my-test  
               -->build.log
               -->inoker.properties
               -->pom.xml
               -->verify.groovy
```

When I try to run a single integration tests as described https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/usage.html. It gives a message that ' No projects were selected for execution' Here is the command I used to invoke the project

```
/src/main> mvn invoker:run -Dinvoker.test=first-test/my-test*
```

How should I make sure the test is run?

Comment: It looks like you misunderstood the docs how to structure your integration tests. The first integration test should be located `/src/it/first-test` the second integration test should be located `/src/it/second-test` which means your folder `my-test` should be removed...Furthermore you should start the integration test from your project root and not by `mvn invoker:run ` you should use `mvn verify -Dinvoker.test=first-test` instead...

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you want to answer it so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you misunderstood the docs how to structure your integration tests. The first integration test should be located `/src/it/first-test` the second integration test should be located `/src/it/second-test` which means your folder `my-test` should be removed...Furthermore you should start the integration test from your project root and not by `mvn invoker:run` you should use `mvn verify -Dinvoker.test=first-test` instead...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are executing it from `src/main`. Try it again from the root of the project (where the pom.xml is located).